# MongoDB Node JS UpdateOne Error: cyclic dependency detected

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making a post request and depending on if the post succeeded, I update one document in my MongoDB database.

I am getting the error:

Did not update MongoDB cardHolderDoc but post worked.

```
Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (/Users/haydenmonarch/Desktop/NewSparkle/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:333:34)
    at serializeInto...
```

Here is my function call:

```
let cardHolderResponse = await sendRequest(XML, completeOrder, id);
```

Here is my function:

```
async function sendRequest(xml, order, custID) {
        const url = 'APIURL';
        const opts = {
            body: xml,
            headers: {
                // 'Encoding': 'UTF-8',
                'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
                'SOAPAction': 'API'
            }
        }

        fixieRequest.post(url, opts, async (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                return db.collection('orders').updateOne(
                    {  id: custID },
                    {
                        $set: {
                            holder: err
                        } 
                    }                
                ).then(success => {
                    return success;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return err;
                })
            } else {
                return db.collection('orders').updateOne(
                    {  id: custID },
                    {
                        $set: {
                            holder: response
                        } 
                    }                
                ).then(success => {
                    return success;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return err;
                })
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say you got the response and in else is the issue , what do you've in response ?

Comment: The post is happening successfully, but the database is not updating after a successful post request.

Comment: yes, I get that, what do you've in response object that got returned ?

Comment: The response object is a successful SOAP request notification. Are my return statements in the correct spot?

Comment: seems to be ok apart from making async func's everywhere- use awaits if you need to wait on db calls, it's not an issue. Did you try the same query in DB ? Are you able to update document ?

Comment: `Are my return statements in the correct spot?` Not at all. You're trying to return from callback which doesn't work in JS

Answer (score 0):

your problem is related to 'err' response from request. When you parse 'err' to JSON your problem will be solved